# Can we have a feature which will enforce users to add comments after down voting a question or answer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I have been a victim of serial de-voting over last 4 months, which system did recognized couple of times, but it gets bit annoying when someone continuously devotes your question/answers without putting any comments down.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been asked several times on MSO, and the answer is always a resounding no.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the links to some of the discussion (*ad nauseam*) that has occurred on meta.stackoverflow.com.

[Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

[Why not allow downvote only with at least an anonymous comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32226/why-not-allow-downvote-only-with-at-least-an-anonymous-comment)

[Down Voters Should be Forced to Leave a Comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87140/down-voters-should-be-forced-to-leave-a-comment)

Just for those who aren't aware, SharePoint.StackExchange.com is built on the StackOverflow platform, so we (the SharePoint moderators) aren't actually responsible for the way the site works.

Answer (score 3):

Requiring people to explain their downvote only encourages argument. If allowed, I see this scenario playing out:

- Comment: I downvoted this for reasons X, Y, and Z.
- Original poster: That is invalid because of A, B, and C.
- Comment: Sorry, but I do not feel that A, B, and C address X, Y, and Z, and additionally, even if they do, you didn't do a good enough job explaining this in your original answer.
- OP: Well, that's YOUR opinion, and opinions are not allowed on SE, and therefore you should be banned!

It's not required to explain an upvote; why should you explain a downvote? People are already (mildly) disincentivized from giving them in that a downvote removes a little bit of your own reputation as well.

Comment: I completely agree John!!!