# getting marked down after accepted answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, moderation

Iv just been marked down on one of my answers yet its marked as an answer!

I dont get why someone would do that? If a person was to have an issue than they would ask a question to get an answer that relates to their problem as it could be somthing else that is causing the issue... but in this case its the correct answer for the op's question and find it unjustified that i get marked down for no apparent reason!

or have i got every thing wrong?

[External access gives a blank home page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60957/external-access-gives-a-blank-home-page/60962#60962)

shouldnt there be no marking down once an answer is excepted or atleast force a comment if the answer is accepted and someone marks you down?

Also like to note that the op's question that i answered is correct as its his exact issue that seems to be a common issue! I am asking on two issues, is the downvote valid? I think not as its correct and solves the op's question! also that the answer is marked as accepted, surely if its accepted than its solves the OP's question and not some other issue, if it doesnt work for others than clearly its a different underlying issue that should be asked? but than if they think what iv done is wrong or does not accord to best practice than surely they should comment as its been accepted and correct! i would understand if it wasnt or if its wrong but accepted than they have a valid downvote!

Comment: Personally when I read your questions, it feels like you're all over the place, with punctuation and weird interjections, it makes it difficult to understand sometimes and could be a source of downvotes for others.

Comment: I've had the same situation on one of my answers. When getting downvoted without a comment it hurts more than it should. But I guess you just have to reboot :)

Comment: @PirateEric sorry but dont have loads of time on my hands to check spelling and grammer :( too busy at work and only answer question whilst waiting for processes to finish lol, I will try better to make it more readable ;)

Comment: @RobertLindgren I feel you brother ;) it hurts when you spend your time to help someone and you know its correct to be shot down because someone maybe with little experience decides he doesnt like your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People downvoting without a comment is unfortunate behaviour, and something that's been frequently discussed in the past:

[why cant we see who down/upvoted you?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/766/why-cant-we-see-who-down-upvoted-you?rq=1)

[Can we have a feature which will enforce users to add comments after down voting a question or answer](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/768/can-we-have-a-feature-which-will-enforce-users-to-add-comments-after-down-voting?rq=1)

[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

[Why not allow downvote only with at least an anonymous comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32226/why-not-allow-downvote-only-with-at-least-an-anonymous-comment)

In the context of an accepted answer, people are still allowed to express their opinion via voting, as the OP's version of the correct answer may not be the same as the community's.

Comment: but that is my point exactly! OP's question was answered as it solved his issue, someone could have the same issue but that problem or cause is somthing unrelated! so surely its ment to be based on the op's question and not what others think? as there could be numerous answers to a question that could be right for others but not for the op's question! The answer what i belive should be purely based on op's question otherwise they should ask a new question or if they belive its wrong to aleast comment why its wrong as the op obviously marked it as right as a solution to his problem?

Comment: Stack Exchange is based around the ethos of creating a definitive Question and Answer that can help many people: A community FAQ, if you like. This is why we have the option to flag a question as a duplicate. By contrast, MSDN is based on a one-question-per-user's-problem as you describe, and it is more acceptable there to re-ask and re-answer slight variants on the same question.

Comment: i do understand that, but how is it constructive of the person downvoting? he has left no comment, the answer is accepted and is correct... i would understand if it wasnt or not marked as correct. I think its just in spite or just for the sake of marking down! Im sure any sharepoint developer or admin who actually reads the op's question and my answer they would see its correct!

Comment: I think you're taking the downvote too seriously. Anyone with 125 rep can downvote, and I doubt it's malicious. Or maybe they were just having a bad day and took their frustrations out on you. Either way, venting on meta will not resolve the problem.

Comment: It's 10 points, not that big of a deal, I've been down voted on valid answers too.

Comment: @PirateEric I once had 3 downvotes on an SO answer that was correct, but not definitive enough!

Answer (score 3):

Having already debated the intrinsic problem of uncommented downvotes, which as far as I am concerned only add noise unless the reason behind them is immediately clear (just to reasume my reasoning, when you downvote without comment you are basically creating doubt in an answer validity and therefore incrementing the confusion of whoever may be reading the thread, hoping for a solution to his/her problem), I can only say that downvotes happens and will continue to happen. Don't give it to much though.

Anyway, about your specific answer... I can only presume that whoever casted the down vote casted it because your answer as now is more centered on explaining WHAT is the minimal download strategy that exploring WHY it seems to hang in the asker environment (at least, I assume it hangs halfway, based on the asker writings). Probably he accepted it because he has resolved the problem by disabling the feature... but this wouldn't still explain why the problem existed firsthand. That just my theory, so take it with a grain of salt... and no, it wasn't me so I can only guess the reasoning ^_^.